# Как добавить в ListBox(select) строки из файла?

Tags: html

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить в такой элемент строки из **файла** и вообще, возможно ли это:
*Пример ListBox(select)*
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без `javascript` тут не обойтись.
Чтобы считать файл можно использовать [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29176118/6196347), добавить пункт в `Select` [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_add.asp).
В файле каждый новый элемент должен сопровождаться пробелом.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <form>
    <select id="mySelect" size="8">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Pear</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
  </select>
  </form>
  <br>

  <input type='file' accept='text/plain' onchange='openFile(event)'><br>

  <script>
    var openFile = function(event) {
      var input = event.target;

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function() {
        var text = reader.result;
        add(text);
      };

      reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
    };


    function add(text) {
      var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
      var arrText = text.split(' ');
      for (var i = 0; i < arrText.length; i++) {
        if (arrText[i] !== '') {
          var option = document.createElement("option");
          option.text = arrText[i];
          x.add(option);
        }
      }

    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое :) Уже сделал на стороне сервера правда, но это гениальный ответ!